# HTML form data posts in ASP.NET Core MVC - http error 405 method not allowed, or parameters are null

Tags: post, asp.net-core-mvc, multipartform-data

I am migrating a project from NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.

In the original application, there is a controller that accepts some string arguments:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(string one, string two, string three)
{
}
```

This endpoint is called by our customers.

We have a basic HTML page used for testing this works which uses HTML form data similar to this

```
<form action="https://example.com/controllerName/Index" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="one" id="one">
    <input type="text" name="two" id="two">
    <input type="text" name="three" id="three">
</form>
```

This all works in .NET Framework but in .NET 6 all requests return a http error 405 "Method Not Allowed". It doesn't reach the action method.

I tried adding a `[HttpGet]` or `[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]` attribute on the action method. I would prefer not to allow `GET` requests and have only tried this out of desperation

Using Postman I found there is no more http 405 "Method Not Allowed" response and this works for any requests that use URL parameters, but for a form-data post the request arrives in the method but all of the parameter values are null.

I tried using a single DTO object with string properties for each of the string values that the customers need to send to us. I also tried the `[FromBody]` attribute.

Comment: Were you just debugging your project or it has been published?

Comment: The NET Framework application is in production and we need to replace it with the .NET 6 application a.s.a.p. I could see that all incoming parameter values are null using the Visual Studio debugger. We really want to avoid having to ask our clients to change their code that uses our web service if at all possible.

Comment: Is your controller class inherit from  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller class?

Comment: Yes it is inheriting from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller

Comment: Is your HttpPost attribute under the namespace :Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc?Could you provide a nimimal example could reproduce the issue?

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProjectName.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string argOne, string argTwo)
        {
            return Ok(argOne);
        }
    }
}

Then make a HTTP POST request using Postman or similar tool. It returns 405 Method Not Allowed. If the action method is changed to return JsonResult instead of IActionResult, the request still results in a 405 Method Not Allowed response.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was due to URL rewrite logic in program.cs

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectLowerCaseRule());
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

In the RedirectLowerCaseRule class, the StatusCode was being changed to HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently

Due to the Post/Redirect/Get pattern the request was getting changed from a POST request to a GET request before it reached the Controller endpoint.

As explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301

"Although the specification requires the method and the body to remain unchanged when the redirection is performed, not all user-agents meet this requirement. Use the 301 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods and use the 308 Permanent Redirect for POST methods instead, as the method change is explicitly prohibited with this status."

One way to solve this is with the method:

```
public int GetStatusCode(string requestMethod)
{
    return (int)(requestMethod.ToUpper() == "POST" ? HttpStatusCode.PermanentRedirect : HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
}
```